# UIImageJPEGRepresentation returns nil when file at specified path is deleted in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uiimagejpegrepresentation

I'm completely confused as to how `UIImageJPEGRepresentation` is related to a file's path in the Documents directory.

Basically, when I delete a file from a file path, and then call `UIImageJPEGRepresentation` on a `UIImage`, it returns nil, but if the file path is not deleted, `UIImageJPEGRepresentation` returns the data representation of the image.

Here's my sample code to demonstrate what I mean:

```
func functionA()
{
    if imagePaths_ARRAY.isEmpty == false
    {
        for pathToDelete in imagePaths_ARRAY
        {
            if fileManager.fileExists(atPath: pathToDelete)
            {
                do
                {
                    try fileManager.removeItem(atPath: pathToDelete)
                }
                catch let error as NSError
                {
                    print(error.localizedDescription)
                }
            }
            else
            {
                print("ERROR")
            }
        }

        imagePaths_ARRAY.removeAll()
    }

    print(images_ARRAY)

    for image in images_ARRAY
    {
        print(image)

        if let imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 0.5)
        {
            print("RETURN GOOD")
            let imageName = getImageName()

            let imagePath = getDirectoryPath().appending("/" + imageName)

            let success = fileManager.createFile(atPath: imagePath, contents: imageData, attributes: nil)

            if success == true
            {
                imagePaths_ARRAY.append(imagePath)
            }
        }
        else
        {
            print("RETURN NIL")
        }

    }
}
```

The very **FIRST** time `functionA` is called, `imagePaths_ARRAY` is empty so the inside block of code does not execute. I loop through an array of `UIImages` and for each image, I call `UIImageJPEGRepresentation` to convert it to a `Data` object to write to file, and I add the `imagePath` to my `imagePaths_ARRAY` array to be used elsewhere in my code.

For each image, I see a log of `RETURN GOOD` and all the images are written to file.

However, when `functionA` is called the **SECOND** time,`imagePaths_ARRAY` is not empty, so I delete all the files from the paths in `imagePaths_ARRAY`.

But when `UIImageJPEGRepresentation` is called on the `image` again, it returns nil?

I am completely confused as to why because each `image` in `images_ARRAY` gives me a valid `UIImage`:

```
[<UIImage: 0x600000085280> size {4288, 2848} orientation 0 scale 1.000000]
```

As mentioned in the first sentence, I like to know how removing a file using `removeItem` causes `UIImageJPEGRepresentation` to return nil?

**UPDATE:** when I replace `UIImageJPEGRepresentation` with `UIImagePNGRepresentation` instead, the image is compressed just fine. I'm completely confused!

Comment: why are you deleting the path ?

Comment: @Optimus: the paths need to be deleted to perform other functionality in my app

Comment: Are you doing anything to your `images_ARRAY` between calls to `functionA`? If so, that could be the problem - your image data may no longer be in a format that can be "jpeg represented". Try to reduce what's going on to debug the issue...

Comment: @DonMag I'm not doing anything else to `images_ARRAY` between calls. If I comment how the check for `imagePaths_ARRAY.isEmpty == false`, then `UIImageJPEGRepresentation` has no issues with the conversion, or even just commenting out `try fileManager.removeItem(atPath: pathToDelete)` and it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like something else *must* be going on in your code.

I just gave it a try, and with the following code I can tap the button repeatedly and every time through I get success:

```
//
//  TestViewController.swift
//

import UIKit

class TestViewController: UIViewController {

    var imagePaths_ARRAY = [String]()
    var images_ARRAY = [UIImage]()

    let fileManager = FileManager.default

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let names = ["s1", "s2", "s3"]

        for s in names {
            if let img = UIImage(named: s) {
                images_ARRAY.append(img)
            }
        }
    }

    @IBAction func btnTapped(_ sender: Any) {
        functionA()
    }


    func getDirectoryPath() -> String {
        return NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)[0]
    }

    func getImageName() -> String {
        let randomNum:UInt32 = arc4random_uniform(1000000)
        return "randomName_\(randomNum)"
    }

    func functionA()
    {

        print(imagePaths_ARRAY)

        if imagePaths_ARRAY.isEmpty == false
        {
            for pathToDelete in imagePaths_ARRAY
            {
                if fileManager.fileExists(atPath: pathToDelete)
                {
                    do
                    {
                        try fileManager.removeItem(atPath: pathToDelete)
                    }
                    catch let error as NSError
                    {
                        print(error.localizedDescription)
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    print("ERROR")
                }
            }

            imagePaths_ARRAY.removeAll()
        }

        print(images_ARRAY)

        for image in images_ARRAY
        {
//          print(image)

            if let imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 0.5)
            {
                let imageName = getImageName()

                let imagePath = getDirectoryPath().appending("/" + imageName)

                let success = fileManager.createFile(atPath: imagePath, contents: imageData, attributes: nil)

                if success == true
                {
                    print("RETURN GOOD")
                    imagePaths_ARRAY.append(imagePath)
                }
            }
            else
            {
                print("RETURN NIL")
            }

        }

    }

}
```

Comment: just to clarify as I havent gotten a chance to test the code out, but when you tap a button, I can see that the first thing the code does is delete each file that points to `pathToDelete`, then loops through `images_ARRAY` and calls `UIImageJPEGRepresentation`, the exact same thing as my code, but you are stating it never outputs `RETURN NIL`, i.e. it is successful in writing the image to file?

Comment: Correct... it prints "RETURN GOOD" every time.

Comment: currently looking through my code, but I'm curious, why do you think `UIImageJPEGRepresentation` is returning nil....clearly before the conversion, I do see a valid `UIImage` being passed into the function, so I'm a big confused why the `UIImage` cannot be converted..I know you stated "your image data may no longer be in a format that can be jpeg represented"..can you elaborate more on what you mean?

Comment: Looking at Apple's docs, there could be a couple reasons. Something that jumps to mind though -- your original post shows `size {4288, 2848}` ... How many of that size image are you trying to hold in `images_ARRAY`? Is it possible you are running out of memory, and while the image *reference* is valid, the image *data* isn't actually in memory?

Comment: Your suggestion seems plausible, but I'm only storing one image from the Photo Library into `images_ARRAY`.....what has me completely baffled is as I mentioned before, if I comment out `try fileManager.removeItem(atPath: pathToDelete)`, it works just fine and prints `RETURN GOOD`, so nothing that I'm doing to `images_ARRAY` is any different than if `try fileManager.removeItem(atPath: pathToDelete)` is not commented out, which has me pulling my hair out in frustration!..I dont understand how `UIImageJPEGRepresentation's` conversion is in any way related to the file path of a file.

Comment: I guess I'd have to see the rest of your code to try and figure it out... Can you create a small example project that replicates the problem?